# PyMongo Integer Overflow? Not an Integer? huge numbers where it should be <3k

Tags: python, printing, overflow, pymongo

Data has been uploaded into MBD by an app I have no access to.
When printing filtered outputs, a specific value I'm looking for somehow apparently exceeds the 32 bit range, although (as 3GPP specified this particular value) it should not exceed 1282.
Most of the values do make sense however, which leads me to believe the app worked properly. 
I don't know how the value is formatted, but I'm guessing it has something to do with it not being an Integer or smth?

Specifically, I'm looking to get a *possible* **time advance radio** value.
(Hopefully the solution might also be applicable for the other "2147483647"s in there)

```
    c = db.get_collection("measurements")
results = (c.find(( {"timestamp": {"$gt": datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 12, 25, 1)}})))

for x in results:
        pprint.pprint(x)
```

outputs:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5e1b03141fea68001f5fd50c'),
 'battery': 0.38,
 'cell_info': [{'active': True,
                'cell_identity': {'cell_id': '20649231',
                                  'e_utra_absolute_radio_frequency_channel_number': '3350',
                                  'location_area_code': '58612',
                                  'mobile_country_code': '262',
                                  'mobile_network_code': '3',
                                  'physical_cell_id': '70'},
                'cell_signal_strength': {'asu': '30',
                                         'channel_quality_indicator': '2147483647',
                                         'dbm': '-110',
                                         'reference_signal_received_power': '-110',
                                         'reference_signal_received_quality': '-6',
                                         'reference_signal_signal_to_noise_ratio': '2147483647',
                                         **'timing_advance_radio': '2147483647'**},
                'type': 'LTE'},
               {'active': False,
                'cell_identity': {'cell_id': '2147483647',
                                  'e_utra_absolute_radio_frequency_channel_number': '3350',
                                  'location_area_code': '2147483647',
                                  'mobile_country_code': '262',
                                  'mobile_network_code': '3',
                                  'physical_cell_id': '288'},
                'cell_signal_strength': {'asu': '24',
                                         'channel_quality_indicator': '2147483647',
                                         'dbm': '-116',
                                         'reference_signal_received_power': '-116',
                                         'reference_signal_received_quality': '-13',
                                         'reference_signal_signal_to_noise_ratio': '2147483647',
                                         'timing_advance_radio': '2147483647'},
                'type': 'LTE'},
               {'active': False,
                'cell_identity': {'cell_id': '2147483647',
                                  'e_utra_absolute_radio_frequency_channel_number': '3350',
                                  'location_area_code': '2147483647',
                                  'mobile_country_code': '262',
                                  'mobile_network_code': '3',
                                  'physical_cell_id': '14'},
                'cell_signal_strength': {'asu': '16',
                                         'channel_quality_indicator': '2147483647',
                                         'dbm': '-124',
                                         'reference_signal_received_power': '-124',
                                         'reference_signal_received_quality': '-17',
                                         'reference_signal_signal_to_noise_ratio': '2147483647',
                                         'timing_advance_radio': '2147483647'},
                'type': 'LTE'}],
 'location_information': {'accuracy': 6.0,
                          'age': -1531,
                          'altitude': 395.0,
                          'latitude': 49.0154534,
                          'longitude': 12.0624561},
 'source_id': ObjectId('5c923e85b3f23b0010f0cec9'),
 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 12, 11, 29, 12),
 'version': 'c79a820'}
```

Hopefully you guys can figure out whats happening here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That data is encoded as a string, so while erroneous, there's nothing technically wrong with it. Also you need to frame your question in a less generalised way than "can figure out whats happening here" because we don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Alright, specifically my question is: How can the output be 2147483647 if the values can only be between 0 and 1282 and how do I fix this?

Comment: Speak to whoever is providing the data and ask them? If no luck there you can wither fix the data up with an `update()` or handle the incorrect data in your downstream program.